# Is there a way to reduce noise in image while subtracting background?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to subtract the background of the image to create a silhouette image for further processing. My image dataset looks like this image:

[image: this image]

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame = cv2.imread("test.png")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = np.array([0, 0, 120])
upper_blue = np.array([180, 38, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
b, g, r = cv2.split(result)  
filter = g.copy()

ret,mask = cv2.threshold(filter,10,255, 1)
frame[ mask == 0] = 255

cv2.imwrite("123.png", mask)
```

The result I got is:

[image: result]

Now I have tried to find and apply contours but it doesn't work

```
contours_mask, hierachy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in range(len(contours_mask)):
    # create mask
    if contour != 1:
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask_b, contours_mask[contour], (0, 0, 0))
```

Is there a way to remove the noise and get a result like this image?

[image: Required Result]

Comment: Your expected output has way more detail than is visible in the input image. You're very unlikely to get results like that without adding some priors (e.g. fitting a model with that much detail to the image). If this is part of a sequence (multiple sequential frames) then you can use the difference between frames for additional information.

Comment: Your could use AI/Deep Learning. http:remove.bg does a nice job with this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, to get an approximate silhouette of the person, you can use OSTU's method.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image, convert to grayscale
frame = cv2.imread("test.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# binarize image using OSTU's method
*_, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image]

The output mask is very close to actual result, however, if you want to refine the mask, i would suggest to use `cv2.grabCut` function, to extract foreground and background segments.

```
# get the bounding box of the silhouette
contours, *_ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# initialize grabCut's parameters
mask_refined = np.empty_like(mask)
fgd_model = np.zeros((1, 65))
bgd_model = np.zeros((1, 65))
iter_count = 10
mode = cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT

# segment image
mask_refined, bgd_model, fgd_model = cv2.grabCut(frame, mask_refined, rect, bgd_model, fgd_model, iter_count, mode)

# select foreground and background
output = np.where((mask_refined == cv2.GC_BGD) | (mask_refined == cv2.GC_PR_BGD), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

[image]